# Unable to return the url string, although able to console.log it. Not sure why

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda function, where I am storing a file in s3 using s3.upload, then I am trying to get a presigned URL `s3.getSignedUrl` so that an external user can download the file I uploaded.

Now when I put a console.log to log the url, the url is getting logged in cloudwatch, however when I try to return the same in the very next line, it does not work.

```
 s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
                    Bucket: '<Bucket-Name>',
                    Key: '<Key>',
                    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
                }, function(err, url){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log(url);
                    return { ...response, body: JSON.stringify({message: url}) };            
                })
            });
        });

        return { ...response, body: JSON.stringify({message: 'outsideresult'}) };
```

This is a part of the code, the console.log line is able to log `url`, however `url` is not getting returned.

And the outer return statement is executed.

The url works as it is supposed to though. Please check, if anyone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

That's because this code is executed asynchronously. The function that you pass as callback `function(err, url)` is called when the operation succeeds. If you return something in the callback function, it is not returned the the original scope

`s3.getSignedUrl` method doesn't return the value you pass from inside the callback

If you execute the below code with console.logs, you'll see that the main function returns first and then the callback returns whereas it should be the other way around
That's how javascript works

```
 s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
                    Bucket: '<Bucket-Name>',
                    Key: '<Key>',
                    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
                }, function(err, url){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log(url);
                    //This is executed later. Returning something here has no effect
                    console.log("Callback returns")
                    return { ...response, body: JSON.stringify({message: url}) };            
                })
            });
        });
console.log("Main Function returns")
        return { ...response, body: JSON.stringify({message: 'outsideresult'}) };
```

Answer (score 0):

Because last statement i.e.

`return { ...response, body: JSON.stringify({message: 'outsideresult'}) };`

executed before the callback.

```
`function(err, url){ 
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(url);
      return { ...response, body: JSON.stringify({message: url}) }; 
     })`
```

so when this callback executed it only logs the statement on the console.so do some updation in your logic.